# Body smaller than the browser window

Tags: html, css

I'm editing my Tumblr's theme, and I've a problem. In Tumblr you have to edit every type of post (text post, photo post, video post etc.). So, when I've edit the text post, the body has shrunk.
See to understand: [tlicetlac.tumblr.com](http://tlicetlac.tumblr.com). The body has got a background-image and an inset shadow. Before editing text post the body's shadow filled all the window... now it fill only about half of the window. With the safari's code inspector I observe that the body is as small as the shadow but his background fill the window.
This is body's css

```
body{
        box-shadow:
        inset 0px 20px 700px black;
        padding:0px;
        background-attachment:fixed;
        background-image:URL("http://cl.ly/image/11340r2A0A24/sfondo%20MAIN.jpeg");
        font-family:Minecraftia;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
    }
```

I've tried to set `Height:100%` but it don't work.

What it could be?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
#posts {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    overflow: hidden; //add this
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Not part of the question but you could also do with:

```
.cartello { overflow:hidden; }
.adescrizione,.bdescrizione { overflow:hidden;overflow-y:auto; }
```

Comment: .cartello and .adescrizione could also do with overflow: hidden. Scrollbars are ugly.

Comment: @isherwood Yea, added an extra bit on the answer (allowed auto on `overflow-y` in case those descriptions get longer)

Comment: Thanks! This work fine! But there isn't a way to hide the scrollbars and able the scroll?

Comment: You probably don't want to take away that visual cue. Do like Smokey says and allow vertical scrolling only.

Comment: @FedericoGrassilli the `auto` value will hide the scrollbars when the container isn't scrollable, and show them when it can be.

Comment: Ok, I didn't see the difference because on Mac scrollbars are hide.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not only with body, there is problem with html too.

Just add:

```
html,
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

if problem is horizontal:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

or if vertical:

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Comment: You responded to a 7 year old thread. I seriously hope that Frederico solved the issue by now. :)

Comment: There will be probably other people come here to see solution.

Answer (score -1):

Set height 100% to both `<body>` and `<html>`:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

`<html>` is the outer element, so that is the one you want to stretch.

Body fills `<html>` (the `100%`).